# Uniform convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha x^{2n} (1-x)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha x^{2n} (1-x)^2$$

a) Determine for every $\alpha$ where the series converges.
b) Show for every $\alpha$ if there is uniform convergence at $[-1,0]$ or $[0,1]$.

Can anybody help me out here a little bit ? How should I tackle this problem ?

Comment: I suspect it should be $(1-x)^{2n}$. Otherwise, just get rid of $(1-x)^2$.

Comment: @julien It is $(1-x)^2$.

Comment: Then the factor $(1-x)^2$ has nothing to do with the convergence of the series. You can factor it out. Except for the case $x=1$ which forces the series to converge since the general term becomes $0$.

Comment: @julien For $[-1,0]$ i think there is only convergence at $\alpha<-1$. For $[0,1]$ there must be uniform convergence at $\alpha<-1$, but I'm not sure for $\alpha\geq -1$.

Comment: Like I said, forget $(1-x)^2$ and consider the convergence of $\sum n^\alpha x^{2n}$. This is an even power series. So what happens on $[0,1]$ happens the same way on $[-1,0]$. How can you find differences between these to cases?

Comment: @julien I can prove it is not uniform for $\alpha \geq -1$ for $[-1,0]$, as $x=-1$ diverges. But for $[0,1]$ I thought about this. If I take calculate the supremum of $f_n(x)$ I find that this is at $\frac{n}{n+1}$, which gives: $f_n(\frac{n}{n+1})=n^\alpha (\frac{n}{n+1})^{2n}(1-\frac{n}{n+1})^2= n^\alpha ((1+ \frac{1}{n})^{n})^{-2}(\frac{1}{n+1})^2\leq n^\alpha \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\leq n^{(\alpha-2)}$. And this would mean it also converges at $\alpha\in [-1,1)$. Right ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Use Root Test.

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^{\alpha}x^{2n}(1-x)^2} $$

So, you get both answers from this. Does not depend on $\alpha$ but on $x$.

**edit** the absolute sign is missing.

Comment: Shouldn't I take the n'th root. I get that it is convergent at $|x^2|<1$, and divergent at $|x^2|>1$. Convergent at $x=1$ and only convergent at $x=-1$ if $\alpha\leq -1$. Correct ?

Comment: You want to add some absolute values.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's nth root. Your solution looks good to me. But listen to julien.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use ratio test to see for what values of $\alpha$ the series converges.

**Added:** For part $(b)$, you need to use the [M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) for uniform convergence. Note that

$$ |n^{\alpha} x^{2n}| \leq n^{\alpha},\,\,\,    |x|\leq 1 . $$

Now, you should be able to see for what $\alpha$ the series converges uniformly.

Comment: I've solved the first question, but I don't know how to show uniform convergence at $[0,1]$. Any ideas ?